# Converting a Javascript JSON.stringfy string to an object using c# JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, windows-8, json.net

I am developing a windows 8 app, and i have some javascript that stores a serialized object into roaming settings, i.e:

```
var object = [{"id":1}, {"id":2}]
roamingSettings.values["example"] = JSON.stringify(object);
```

I also i have a c# part to the application (for running a background task), that needs to read that JSON, and turn it into an object so i can iterate over it. And this is where i am having some issues, i am using JSON.NET to do the work, but every thing i turn turns up with an error:

```
// this looks like "[{\"id\":1},{\"id\":2}]"
string exampleJSON = roaming.Values["example"].ToString();
// dont know if this is correct:
List<string> example = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(exampleJSON );
```

That give an error of:

> Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path '[0]', line 1, position 2.

So i am at a loss of what to do, i have been working on it for last few hours, and i am quite unfamiliar with c#, so resorting to the help of stackoverflow ;D

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to parse your JSON array into a List of strings, which doesn't work. The JSON object you provide is actually a list of objects containing an integer property called 'id'.

Perhaps try creating a class (say, MyClass) with just that property, and deserialize into List.

Answer (score 2):

Json.Net has a nice method `DeserializeAnonymousType`. No need to declare a temporary class.

```
string json = "[{\"id\":1},{\"id\":2}]";
var anonymous = new []{new{id=0}};
anonymous = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json,anonymous);

foreach (var item in anonymous)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.id);
}
```

You can even use the `dynamic` keyword

```
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
foreach (var item in dynObj)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your json containts a collection of objects with an `id` property, something like this:

```
class IdObject {
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

You could then do:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<IdObject>>(exampleJSON);
```

Because the `IdObject` class has a property `id` to match your json serialized value, it will be mapped back.